# Find specific numbers/positions in string

Tags: php, int, preg-replace, trim

I need to get numbers from strings like that:

```
main-section1-1
...
main-section1-512
...
main-section10-12
```

At first maybe i need to get out of letters from string:

```
preg_replace("/[^0-9-]+/i", "", $string);
```

...but what's next?

For example:

```
$string = 'main-section1-1';
```

Expected result:

```
$str1 = 1;
$str2 = 1;
```

or:

```
$str = array(1,1);
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: "but what's next?" You tell us. Did you try that? If so, what was the expected result vs the actual result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
$string = "main-section1-1";
preg_match_all( "/[0-9]+/", $string, $match );
print_r($match);

// for main-section1-512, you will get 1 and 512 in $match[0]
?>
```

Output:

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I don't misunderstood your question this will work for you https://eval.in/875419

```
$re = '/([a-z\-]+)(\d+\-\d+)/';
$str = 'main-section1-512';
$subst = '$2';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
list($str1,$str2) = explode('-',$result);
echo $str1;
echo "\n";
echo $str2
```